# Define Library Search Path for 3rd Party Lib in iOS Cordova Plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcode8, cordova-plugins

I am building a Cordova plugin to interface with a 3rd-party library that I am unable to modify.  The library includes two separate `.a` files: one that will build for the iOS simulator and that builds for a device.  Using the wrong one for the target will cause the build to fail.

I've added both libraries to the plugin in separate folders (since they're named the same).  When the plugin is added to a project, Cordova adds separate Library Search Paths for each library.  Unfortunately this means that whichever path is listed first is the one included when the project is built.  This means that I have to tell the users of my plugin to "go into settings, find X field on tab Y, switch the order of these two items."

Xcode has the ability to use variable substitution in the paths but I can't find any information on how to override Cordova's generated search paths with one that includes a substitution.

Here's the code from my plugin's `plugin.xml` file that includes the library:

```
<platform name="ios">
    ...
    <header-file src="src/ios/lib/FooLibrary.h" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/lib/libFooLibrary.a" framework="true" target-dir="iphoneos" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/lib/simulator/libFooLibrary.a" framework="true" target-dir="iphonesimulator" />
</platform>
```

This generates the following Library Search Paths in the containing project:

```
"$(SRCROOT)/PluginDemoApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-foolib/iphoneos"
"$(SRCROOT)/PluginDemoApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-foolib/iphonesimulator"
```

Instead of those two paths, I need it to only generate this single path:

```
"$(SRCROOT)/PluginDemoApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-foolib/${PLATFORM_NAME}"
```

I've added this path manually in Xcode to the containing project and verified that the substitution with `PLATFORM_NAME` will cause Xcode to use the appropriate library for whichever platform is targeted.  I just can't figure out how to configure my plugin so that Cordova will use this path when the plugin is added to a project.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I don't recall if I was able to find a good solution at the time. Unfortunately I don't have access to the code for this anymore so I can't look it up.